# Conceptual help on implementing a rating system that lets items decrease in time

Tags: php, mysql, math, rating

I am running a website that lets users contribute by letting them upload files on specific subjects. Right now my rating system is the worst possible (number of downloads of the file). Not only is this highly inaccurate in terms of quality control but also does it prevent new content to become listed on top anytime soon. 
This is why I want to change my rating system so that users can up-/down-vote each item. However this should not be the only factor to display the popularity of such item. I would like to have older content to decrease in rating over time. Maybe I could even factor in the amount of downloads but to a very low percentage.

So, my questions are:

1. Which formula would you suggest under the assumption that there is 1 new upload every day?
2. How would you implement this in a php/mysql environment?

My problem is that right now I am simply sorting my stuff by the `downloads` row in the database. How can I sort a query by a factor that is calculated externally (in php) or do I have to update a new row in my table with the rating factor each time someone calls the site in his browser?

(Please excuse any mistakes, I am not a native speaker)

Comment: Try this [Reddit Ratings](http://blog.reddit.com/2009/10/reddits-new-comment-sorting-system.html) and from there you can search what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Romain for the link. Very interesting indeed. However, this isn't really helping me as I do not want to rank the comments but the "topics" if you may call them that way. Will be searching up on that tho. Thanks again for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in any case, you **will need** to add at least one column to your table. The best thing would be to have a separate table with `id`, `upvotes`, `downvotes`, `datetime`

If you want to take in consideration the *freshness* of posts (or uploads or comments or...) I think the best actual method is **Wilson score with *a gravity parameter***.

For a good start with Wilson score implementation in PHP, check [this](http://www.derivante.com/2009/09/01/php-content-rating-confidence/).

Then you will need to read [this](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) to understand the pros and the cons of other solutions and use SQL directly.
Remark: *gravity* is not explicitly detailed in the SQL code but thanks to the PHP one you should be able to make it work.

Note that if you would like something simpler but still not lame, you could check with [Bayesian Average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average). **IMDB** uses Bayesian Estimation to calculate its [Top 250](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top).

Implementing your own statistical model will only results in drawbacks that you had not imagined first (too far from the mean, downvotes are more important than upvotes, decay too quickly, etc...)

Finally you are talking about rating uploads directly, not the user who uploads the files. If you would like to do the same with the user, the simpler would be to use a Bayesian estimate with the results from your uploads ratings.

You have a lot to read, just in StackOverflow, to dry the subject.

Your journey starts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rating+algorithm+php)...

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks a lot! Will read it through asap. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I am not really fluent in php or mysql, but as for the rating system, if you want to damp things in time, have you considered a decaying exponential?  Off the top of my head, I would probably do something like

```
$rating = $downloads * exp(-1*$elapsedTime)
```

you can read up on it here  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay.  Maybe build in a one week or one month or something delay before you starting damping the results, or people are going to get their upload downrated immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I read up a bit on the reddit rating (http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588) which is quite appealing, too. However I am still stuck with with how I would manage the sorting call... Thanks a lot anyways. I would upvote if I could...